# How to delete active logins in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, history, browsing

How can I delete active Logins in Internet Explorer 9? I want all logins to be cleared on closing the Internet Explorer 9 browser. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean active logins to whatever application you may be supporting.  In that case, track your users login within the session.  The session is automatically discarded when the IE is closed.

If you mean any logins to other websites you may have logged into, just set your cache to clear on quit.